# write/add data in file using express js

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm trying to write/add data in a json file (for example for each request, a new json is added in the json file) i am using Express.js. I am new to all of this so I really don't know what to do. I'm using a POST request, here's what i got so far. I know it's a big catastrophic mess, i scraped everything that could help me and gathered all of it. I'm just SO lost. Thanks for your help !

```
app.post('*/', function(req, res) {
  res={
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    reponse1: req.body.reponse1,
    reponse2: req.body.reponse2,
  };
  JSON.stringify(res);
  var body =  {
  table: []
  }; 
  body.table.push(res);
  filePath = __dirname + '/data.json';
  req.on('data', function(data) {
     body += data;
  });

  req.on('end', function (){
    fs.appendFile(filePath, body, function() {
         res.end();
    });
});
```

});

Comment: What happens when you run it. is there any error, whats in console?

Comment: no error on the console but i'm using it on a chatbot and they said "Unable to parse JSON" , i think it will work fine with the answer below though ! thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, I see a lot of bugs. Firstly, you should not assign `res = { }`. Secondly, you stringify the JSON data like below. I will also suggest you to go through some tutorials of Node.js first. You can go through https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/ or https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial.

For your requirement, you can simply use following code:

```js
const express  = require('express')
const app      = express()
const bodyParser= require('body-parser')
const fs   = require('fs')


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.post('/', function(req, res){
 var body = {
     first_name: req.body.firstName,
     last_name: req.body.lastName
 }
 filePath = __dirname + '/data.json'

 fs.appendFile(filePath, JSON.stringify(body), function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err }
  res.status(200).json({
   message: "File successfully written"
  })
    })

})

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000")
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! now i receive the error message "Unable to parse JSON" what do you think I should change ?

Comment: i can't, there's no error on the console, only when i launch my bot and send a request to my server it gives me that message. But I think it's an issue related to the plateform i use...